# Special Character "#" won't record in GET method PHP

Tags: php, html, get

I am new to coding. There seems to be a problem when I try to Get the value of "#". Some special characters do work but only the "#" won't work.

when I try to run my link:
http://localhost/php/Final/DeleteTask.php?Username=311&ID_Task=Task#8

This is the output.

```
311
Task
```

The output won't show the value "Task#8". Instead it resulted in "Task"
I have tried doing urldecode but it still won't work.

[My php code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sReCW.png)

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Why not just pass ` http://localhost/php/Final/DeleteTask.php?Username=311&ID_Task=8` and then in the code you can add `Task#` to the front of `ID_Task` if that is required later in the code

Comment: See the duplicate, basically the `#` and anything after it is not sent to the server it is only used in the browser to jump to an anchor in the page. Check out [How to Add an Anchor Link to Jump to a Specific Part of a Page](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html)

Comment: Alright thanks! I apologize for I am new.

Comment: No need to apologise. In future though it is best to do a search with your favourite search engine. at least 75% of the time a beginner will find a question has been asked and answered already :)

Comment: If you want to use `#` as data you'll need to `urlencode` it